# How to search the text between the HTML tags

Tags: javascript, mongodb, full-text-search, mongojs

I'm using mongoJS to process my database query. I came across an issue which the string contains HTML tags, I'm using regex expressions to search my string in the collection. How to search the text by ignore the HTML tags?

```
var userInput = $scope.userInput; // value from user input
db.collections.find({'obj': {$regex: new RegExp(userInput) } }).toArray(function(err, result){ 
  return res.json(result); 
}
```

**Collections**

```
[{_id:"34aw34d343s4", obj:"How are you?"},
{_id:"34asdfwer343s4", obj:"Are you okay?"},
{_id:"3sDaweqr43s4", obj:"Goodbye, my friend!"},
{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
```

**User Input**

```
these are
these
these are important
```

**Output**

```
[{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
[{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
[]
```

**Expected**

```
[{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
[{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
[{_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are <strong>important</strong> items"}]
```

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why are you using a Regex. What is the raw output of the database? I am also finding the input, output and expected information confusing. if you hardcoded the user input to ```var userInput = "these are";``` how come you have 3 different inputs?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara The userInput is an example only. In real case senario, I have bunch of different string inputs.. some don't have HTML tags, some included HTML tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **[sanitize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization)** the user input before it goes into the database. From my understanding of your system, there is a great probability that user input (prior to being inserted in the database)is not sanitized and your site is vulnerable to an [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

I recommend you to use a library like [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) to secure your site against [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and as well as an answer to this question.

Comment: Absolutely agree with this. If you want to add bold content, try saving your data with short-hands and use a front-end library to render it into the DOM.

Example: {_id:"34aw3sdfgds3s4", obj:"Do you know these are \*important\* items"}
You can then use the *'s as pointers for adding a <strong> tag on render. It's safer and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RegExp **test** method:  `/these|are/.test(stringToCheckAgainst);`

```js
var testCases = ["these are", "these", "these are <strong>item</strong>"];

testCases.forEach(function(value) {
  document.write(/these|are/.test(value) + "\n");
});
```

Comment: The output should be an array of objects from collection (MongoDB).

Answer (score -3):

If you want to remove the html tag then the following method

1. jQuery(html).text();
2. yourStr.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
3. yourStr.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');

more on [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but if it does, it's in a nasty way.

Comment: @Matthew Barbara Then what is your solution?

Comment: I need further clarifications on the problem first before I come with a solution as it's not clear to me yet.

Comment: @Matthew Barbara For this, I agree with you, if he want to remove all the content with tag, what is your solution.

Comment: I've replied now. Check my answer and let me know what do you think. Thanks